# Sending multiple 3D arrays to a process in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I have a function which needs to be sent 3 NxNxN arrays (N=300) to perform its calculations. Individual MPI_Sends and MPI_Receives will not work well.

Is there some other construct that I can use ?

Comment: Is there a reason that each structure cannot be sent with a single Send?

Comment: I tend to agree with @Dr.Tower - as a general rule of thumb it's better to send few large messages rather than many small messages, so batching sends makes good sense - but here each array is 103MB (for floats) 206MB (for doubles) in size, so the latency hit from sending each array as an individual send will be small fraction of the communication time.  So I wouldn't worry about it and would just do it as individual sends unless there was a real problem with doing it that way.

Comment: @Dr.Tower I thought batching would improve performance, because I have 3 arrays to send to each function.

Comment: By each structure I meant each 3-D array.  The overhead associated with each array will be minimal compared to the size of the array. Batching 3 of these arrays together will not provide much, if any, measurable benefit. You would be swapping out the overhead of 2 extra sens and receives for the overhead of creating your own specific MPI_Datatype and then deconstructing it on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is stored contiguously, you can send as much of the data at once as you like. Just do:

```
MPI_Send(&data[i][j], 300, MPI_SOMETHING, ...);
```

to send an entire row at a time or:

```
MPI_Send(&data[i], 900, MPI_SOMETHING, ...);
```

to send a 2D slice. Depending on your implementation, there may be some size after which it becomes faster or slower to send your messages so feel free to experiment.